# Band recommendation for someone that likes: Guns n' Roses, Bon Jovi, etc

Tags: rock, alternative-rock

Band recommendation for someone that likes: Guns n' Roses, Bon Jovi, Sebastian Bach, Skid Row, Ramones, Sex Pistols and Foo Fighters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryan Adams, Aerosmith, Three Doors Down, Greenday, Hoobastank, Creed, Nirvana.

Comment: Thanks man, I loved the song Kryptonite by 3 doors down, didn't know them.

Comment: Kryptonite is a good one.  Glad you enjoyed it.